# Does anyone know of a Mental Math Game for blind students?

Tags: arithmetic, mental-arithmetic

I'm looking for any computer game made for blind students where the math exercises are asked through a computer's speaker and answered through a microphone by the student.

Unlike normal math games, answers shouldn't be typed using the keyboard's number pad or such. They **must** be answered In-Voice. The game should feature Mental Math exercises of Adding, Subtracting, Multiplying and dividing two digit numbers if possible.

I know this question sounds demanding and oddly specific but that *IS* in fact what I'm looking for. The game doesn't HAVE to include all these features, it mainly needs to revolve around Mental Math exercises that are answered through voice even if the questions weren't spoken by the game.

I tried to use Google but to no avail. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why specifically answering by voice, rather than by some keys or mouse button ? This constraint seriously reduce the set.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why only through voice is suitable? What about the use of screen readers?